# iPhone 5 my iMessage doesn't work

Tags: messages, iphone

I do not have a SIM card in my phone. Before my iMessage used to work even without a SIM card. But now it doesn't, why?

Comment: did you change the WiFi ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have reinstalled the operating system of Apple just decides to make another change I have not quite figured out yet, I often find myself needing to go in and reenable the iMessage and FaceTime feature. It is fairly straight forward

Go to Settings>Messages and turn off iMessage.
Then go to FaceTime and turn off FaceTime.
Restart your device.
Turn iMessage and FaceTime back on.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are "starting new conversations from" and "receive messages using" your email address and not a phone number. This is done in the messages settings panel in the settings app.